# Como fazer um LIKE ignorando acentuação?

Tags: mysql, codificação-de-caracteres

Estou precisando fazer consultas em um banco de usuários cadastrados. Porém preciso que essa pesquisa seja feita pelo nome do usuário, através do `LIKE`, e este deve ignorar a codificação `UTF-8` presentes nos nomes.

O que quero dizer é o seguinte:

- Quando pesquisar `c`, ele deve encontrar `c` e `ç`.
- Quando pesquisar `a`, quero que ele encontre `à`, `ã` e `á`

Ou seja,

Ao fazer

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios where NOME LIKE 'Maria Magalhaes'
```

Ele encontre a `Maria Magalhães`

Como posso fazer isso no MYSQL?

Comment: Tenta usar `WHERE nome LIKE '%Maria Magalhaes%'`; não sei se isso resolve mas eu acho que não precisa de nada alem do que você já esta fazendo, porque o mysql já compara que "a" e "ã" também são um resultado valido.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM usuarios where NOME LIKE utf8_unicode_ci 'Maria Magalhaes' `

Comment: Não sei porquê seu MySql está assim. Tente trocar a codificação. No meu pesquisei `João`, `joao`, `Joao`, com acento, sem acento, **LCase**, **UCase** e buscou a palavra `João`.

Comment: você também pode fazer direto no código para dar certo também @WallaceMaxters `$con->exec('SET NAMES utf8');`

Comment: Veja, para acentos parece funcionar, não sei quanto ao `ç`...: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8647080/accent-insensitive-search-query-in-mysql . Tenha em mente que uma pesquisa como quer fazer pode trazer problemas de performance, mesmo se o campo original estiver indexado. Há casos assim que a solução é criar uma nova coluna "sanitizada" (sem acentos e `ç`, por exemplo) e indexá-la também, fazendo as buscas usando esta nova coluna. Em geral, esta é a abordagem que acredito ser a mais adotada.

Answer (score 11):

Cara, já passei por isso e resolvi o problema apenas adicionando `collate utf8_general_ci` após o `like '%string%'`, desta forma:

```
Select * from TABELA where CAMPO like '%texto_para_encontrar%' collate utf8_general_ci
```

Não precisei fazer nenhuma alteração no charset do BD ou na página.

Comment: É possível fazer isso no javascript para filtar string na própria DOM? Fiz uma tabela e um input text, que filtra certinho, mas se tem João e digito Joao ele esconde João, não tem a mesma regra e não descubro como fazer

Comment: Tem como sim... Acho que já respondi isso aqui... Vou procurar

Comment: Quando  puder me ajuda por favor.

Comment: Como vc fez esse filtro? O JavaScript diferencia naturalmente acentos.

Comment: Até publiquei a pouco aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/369970/consulta-registros-em-tabela-com-jquery

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente

Answer (score 5):

Resolvi o problema definido as tabelas como `utf8_unicode_ci`

Convertemos o tipo de entrada de caracteres da tabela

```
ALTER TABLE `tabela` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Depois convertemos os dados que já existe para a mesma codificação utilizada na Query acima.

```
ALTER TABLE `tabela`
CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 2):

Os créditos vão para o site SQLFROMHELL
https://sqlfromhell.wordpress.com/2010/05/01/ignorando-letras-maiusculas-minusculas-acentos-e-c/

```
--Quando os textos precisam ser idênticos em nível de minúsculas/maiúsculas, podemos utilizar os COLLATEs com CS:
SELECT
CASE WHEN 'Produção' = 'Produção' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
THEN 1
ELSE 0 END

--Para ignorar a diferença entre as letras maiúsculas e minúsculas, utilizamos COLLATEs com CI:
SELECT
CASE WHEN 'Produção' = 'produção' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
THEN 1
ELSE 0 END

--Quando precisamos ignorar acentos, COLLATES com AI (insensibilidade a acentos):
SELECT
CASE WHEN 'Produção' = 'produçao' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
THEN 1
ELSE 0 END

--Quando precisamos ignorar a diferença até do ç e c, recomendo a utilização de COLLATEs com CI e AI do sistema operacional, exemplo:
SELECT
CASE WHEN 'Produção' = 'producao' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
THEN 1
ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score -2):

```
create or alter function alfaNum (texto varchar(100)) returns varchar(100)
as
  declare variable stAux varchar(100) = '';
BEGIN
  stAux = upper(:texto);
  stAux = replace(stAux, 'Á', 'A');
  stAux = replace(stAux, 'À', 'A');
  stAux = replace(stAux, 'Ã', 'A');
  stAux = replace(stAux, 'Â', 'A');
  stAux = replace(stAux, 'Ä', 'A');
  stAux = replace(stAux, 'É', 'E');
  stAux = replace(stAux, 'Ê', 'E');
  stAux = replace(stAux, 'Ë', 'E');
  stAux = replace(stAux, 'Ï', 'I');
  stAux = replace(stAux, 'Í', 'I');
  stAux = replace(stAux, 'Î', 'I');
  stAux = replace(stAux, 'Ö', 'O');
  stAux = replace(stAux, 'Ó', 'O');
  stAux = replace(stAux, 'Õ', 'O');
  stAux = replace(stAux, 'Ô', 'O');
  stAux = replace(stAux, 'Ò', 'O');
  stAux = replace(stAux, 'Ú', 'U');
  stAux = replace(stAux, 'Ü', 'U');
  stAux = replace(stAux, 'Ç', 'C');
  stAux = replace(stAux, '&', 'E');
  stAux = replace(stAux, '´', ' ');
  stAux = replace(stAux, '^', ' ');
  stAux = replace(stAux, '~', ' ');
  stAux = replace(stAux, 'Æ', 'A');
  stAux = replace(stAux, 'Ñ', 'N');
  stAux = replace(stAux, 'Ý', 'Y');
  stAux = replace(stAux, 'ª', 'A');
  stAux = replace(stAux, 'º', 'O');
  RETURN Upper(stAux);
END
```

Comment: Olá Claudio, isso resolverá tanto para latin1 quanto para utf8 (os 2 mais usados)?

Answer (score -3):

This approach worked for me:

```
const pg = require('pg');

const client = new pg.Client({
  connectionString: `postgres://${process.env.PGROOTUSER}:${process.env.PGROOTPASSWORD}@${process.env.PGHOST}:${process.env.PGPORT}/postgres`,
});
await client.connect();

// make sure your postgresql database has the "unaccent" installed
await client.query(`CREATE EXTENSION  IF NOT EXISTS unaccent;`)

// so you can run a query like this:
await models.City.findOne({
  where: {
    countryId: 'BR',
    districtId: 'RS',
    $and: Sequelize.where(
      Sequelize.fn('unaccent', Sequelize.col(`"City"."name"`)),
      'SAO SEBASTIAO DO CAI',
    ),
  },
});

// in the database city name is 'SÃO SEBASTIÃO DO CAÍ' and it will find it
```