# Consultas com Operador LIKE mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Olá!
Estou tendo um problema ao fazer uma busca com o like mysql. Mina tabela é tipo MyISAM, colation latin1_swedish_ci.

Estou usando php e as consultas utilizando like não estão retornando resultados esperados!

Se eu procuro por exemplo funcionários

```
SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE bairro like '%funcionarios%'
```

não obtenho nenhum registro, só retorna se tiver com acento funcionário.

no banco de dados os dados foram gravados por php utf8 o campo gravado está FuncionÃ¡rios

Acho que o insucesso é devido ao tipo como foi gravado no banco de dados!

Gostaria de saber como resolver essa situação para que possa pesquisar utilizando like sem levar em consideração os acentos! Fazendo a pesquisa direto no banco de dados também não retorna resultado utilizando a expressão com acento.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como fazer um LIKE ignorando acentuação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80775/como-fazer-um-like-ignorando-acentua%c3%a7%c3%a3o)