# Consulta registros em tabela com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Criei uma `input[type='text']` e uma tabela `HTML`, e ao digitar um termo no campo `input[type='text']` o código que fiz consulta strings dentro de todos `<tr><td></td></tr>` e oculta o que não existe nos termos, o objetivo é filtrar resultados de tabela para localizar um registro rapidamente.

```
<div class="row">
    <form class="form-inline" id="searchForm" onSubmit="return false;">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="searchItem" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar por termos na tabela">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>#ID</td>
                <td>Prévia</td>
                <td>Titular</td>
                <td>Relatório</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>948576</td>
                <td><img class='LazyLoad' src='' data-url='./uploads/thumb/{[TRACK_IMG]}'></td>
                <td>João Nascimento Alcântara</td>
                <td><button>Gerar</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>857541</td>
                <td><img class='LazyLoad' src='' data-url='./uploads/thumb/{[TRACK_IMG]}'></td>
                <td>Joao de Nascimento Alcantara</td>
                <td><button>Gerar</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

E o Javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#searchItem").on('keyup', function() {
        var conta = $("#searchItem").val();
        if(conta.length == 0) {
            $("table.table tbody tr").removeAttr('style');
        }
    });
    $('#searchItem').on('keyup', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var input = document.getElementById("searchItem");
        var conta = $("#searchItem").val();
        if(conta.length >= 3) {
            var filter = input.value.toLowerCase();
            var nodes = $("table.table tbody tr");
            for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                if (nodes[i].innerText.toLowerCase().includes(filter)) {
                } else {
                    $(nodes[i]).attr('style','display:none');
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

O que acontece é que se digito Joao (sem acento) o código não reconhece João e assim oculta a linha do registro, quero que o código reconheça João para Joao e João para João, não consegui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use uma função que retira os acentos tanto do termo buscado quando do texto do elemento. A função `tiraAcentos()` retorna o texto já em minúscula e sem acentos. Aí basta você colocá-la no argumento do `if`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   
   function tiraAcentos(i){
      
      var i = i.toLowerCase().trim();
   
      var acentos = "ãáàâäéèêëíìîïõóòôöúùûüç";
      var sem_acentos = "aaaaaeeeeiiiiooooouuuuc";
      
      for(var x=0; x<i.length; x++){
         var str_pos = acentos.indexOf(i.substr(x,1));
         if(str_pos != -1){
            i = i.replace(acentos.charAt(str_pos),sem_acentos.charAt(str_pos));
         }
      }
      
      return i;
   }   

    $("#searchItem").on('keyup', function() {
        var conta = $("#searchItem").val();
        if(conta.length == 0) {
            $("table.table tbody tr").removeAttr('style');
        }
    });
    $('#searchItem').on('keyup', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var input = document.getElementById("searchItem");
        var conta = $("#searchItem").val();
        if(conta.length >= 3) {
            var filter = input.value.toLowerCase();
            var nodes = $("table.table tbody tr");
            for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                if (tiraAcentos(nodes[i].innerText).includes(tiraAcentos(filter))) {
                    $(nodes[i]).show();
                } else {
                    $(nodes[i]).hide();
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <form class="form-inline" id="searchForm" onSubmit="return false;">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="searchItem" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar por termos na tabela">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>#ID</td>
                <td>Prévia</td>
                <td>Titular</td>
                <td>Relatório</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>948576</td>
                <td><img class='LazyLoad' src='' data-url='./uploads/thumb/{[TRACK_IMG]}'></td>
                <td>João Nascimento Alcântara</td>
                <td><button>Gerar</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>857541</td>
                <td><img class='LazyLoad' src='' data-url='./uploads/thumb/{[TRACK_IMG]}'></td>
                <td>Joao de Nascimento Alcantara</td>
                <td><button>Gerar</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfeito, adaptado e funcionando, muito obrigado por tudo mais uma vez.

Comment: Falo jovem. QQ coisa tamos aí

Comment: só pra constar, li e entendi como funciona a função e a adaptação do código rsrsrs valeu

Comment: Talvez o uso do .trim() seja desnecessário. Acho que pode retirar ele

Comment: removi, trato espaço desnecessário na saída, não seria mesmo necessário.